# Django:Complex queryset filter for FK related models

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have many models in this way:

```
Model 1:
key=models.charfield()
....

Model 2:
.....
key=fk(model1, ralated_name='model2key')

model 3:
.....
key=fk(Model 2, related_name='model3key')

models 4:
.....
key=FK(model 3, related_name='model4key')
```

Now i have to write a queryset, for model 4 where i need data filtering considering model 1 = something.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Model4.objects.filter(key__key__key__key="some char value")
```

This will perform three `INNER JOIN`s on `key` field between the tables above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more thing. If after getting filtered values, if i manipulate it further, i mean filter it again. Does it hit DB again, or its a one time job?

Comment: It hits db again.

Comment: Is there a way that DB hit is once and rest filtering is done by python. And being a learner in Django, which is good hitting DB or Python run?

Comment: What kind of filtering logic are we talking about? For instance, there is [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) method that retrieves objects, in a single batch, and does the ‘mapping’ in Python.